# Issue adding attribute values to Laravel model

Tags: php, laravel, oop

I'm trying to create an additional attribute method in a model which appends a ratings label column to an existing rating model. I have the exact same code working for another model which adds click data. I'm getting an Undefined index: rating_label error - can't figure out why? Any help much appreciated.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Rating extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'rating';
    protected $primaryKey = 'rating_id';
    protected $appends = array('rating_label');

    /**
     * Define a 1-many inverse relationship in eloquent
     */
    public function Article()
    {

    return $this->belongsTo(Article::class, 'article_id');// (Model, primary_key)
    }
    /**
     * Add additional column to Rating model for use in ClassifyingService class
     */
    public function getRatingLabelAttribute()//accessor getter/setter
    {
        return $this->attributes['rating_label'];
    }   
}
```

Comment: Check: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/add-custom-attributes-to-eloquent-models

Comment: How are you getting the `rating_label`? i.e. is it a column in the rating table, is it in another table, is it a concatenation of other fields?

Comment: Thanks for the link DanMiller, this is what I had originally read and reading again it seems that using the attributes is not really the best solution for my use case. I'd implemented one of the comments not the recommended solution. @rosswilson the field doesn't exist in my db/model, I was playing around with map and this method to try and temporarily append a field to my dataset. However I'd not implemented correctly.

Comment: I thought that might have been the case as it's looks like you've mixed `accessors` and `mutators`. Do you still need help with it or have you got it sorted now?